# Making an img element's src another element's background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The img element I created works find except for the part where I take another image's background-image and make it this image's source. This is the code I have came up with.

```
var bg = element.css("background-image");
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('"', '');
bg = bg.slice(bg.search("images"));
imgElement.attr('src', '' + bg);
```

when I do

```
imgElement.attr('src', 'images/my-image.png');
```

It works perfectly fine.

This is all triggered when the element with the background image is hovered over.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
var bg = element.css("background-image");
bg = bg.replace(/^url\("(.*)"\)$/,'$1');
bg = bg.substring(bg.indexOf("images") > -1 ? bg.indexOf("images") : 0);
imgElement.attr('src', bg);
```

It only requires one regular expression to remove the `url(` and the ending `)`, and it uses the [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method to work with the string directly. [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) finds the position of the string `"images"` and by passing that to `substring`, it removes everthing that precedes it. `indexOf` returns `-1` if no match is found, in that case we just start from the beginning using a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).